# Lambda details (invocation, duration, errors) are getting delay in Newrelic

Tags: python, aws-lambda, newrelic

I am referring this documentation to see all lambda details like invocations, errors, invocations duration etc. in newrelic:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/serverless-function-monitoring/aws-lambda-monitoring/enable-lambda-monitoring/enable-serverless-monitoring-aws-lambda-legacy#python

**Issue:** Not getting lambda invocation details immediately

we can see all invocations in cloud watch but in newrelic it is showing after some time and that time is fixed. Sometime it is showing after 2-3 hrs, sometimes even more / less, why so?